# Balls and Boxes

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, arithmetic

> Three urns contain marbles. Each urn is large enough to hold all the marbles . The only operation allowed is to move marbles from an urn to another urn, such that the number of marbles in the receiving urn is doubled. Prove that it is possible, regardless of the initial configuration, to obtain a configuration where one urn is empty.

This is an exercice from a french old book. I’ve been trying to solve it since 3 years without any issue.

Comment: If the number of balls in the third box doubles at a stage then can we put remaining balls of the second container to the first one so that the second container is empty?

Comment: This looks like an interesting question. Please give us some context, such as where it comes from, what you've tried so far, etc. Thanks.

Comment: It comes from a Book edited in french language in the arithmetic section.

Comment: If you start with Box 1: 2 balls; Box 2: 2 balls; Box 3: 5 balls, what moves are allowed? No move can increase the number in Box 3 to 10.

Comment: @almagest The question does appear to be worded weirdly. I think it means that there are three boxes and you are allowed to move balls from one box to another box as long as the number of balls in the target box doubles. Thus I suspect that valid moves are moving two balls from either box 1 or 3 to box 2 and moving two balls from either box 2 or 3 to box 1.

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE, As John Omielan asked above, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @jgon Ah, thanks! So if you start with 4,1,7. You could move successively to 4,2,6, then 4,4,4, then 0,8,4.

Comment: I generated some interesting thoughts: the ball transitions between boxes can be expressed as six $3\times 3$ matrices operating on $\mathbb Z^3$. Since the number of balls is constant, these transformations are pushing around points of the plane $x+y+z=n$ where $n$ is the number of balls. The goal is to push a given point to the edge of the triangle this plane cuts in the first quadrant. Of course, this is all overkill if there is an arithmetic answer, but I couldn't help but try to look at what's happening with the geometry...

Comment: One can probably further reduce what I described into an equilateral triangle with lattice points in it.

Comment: Can you write it as an answer to the question?

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE What would be the point of writing an answer with no solution given? Besides, you have not mentioned anything about your progress, yet.

Comment: You edited this question, but you still haven't added context. While the question is somewhat interesting, without context, I have many reasons not to answer it. Not least of which is that your question may be closed and deleted in the future for lack of context.

Comment: I have already say something about the context. This is an exercice from a french old book. I’ve been trying to solve it since 3 years without any issue.

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE Now that it's in the question, that works for me. (Sidenote, I had already upvoted the question, just thought it was important to comment)

Comment: For what it's worth, if there were only two boxes, then it is easy to show you can empty one box iff the total number of balls is a power of 2 times the gcd of the two initial numbers.  So with 3 boxes, it would suffice to reach a state where 2 of the boxes satisify this condition.

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMAREH I cannot help but wondering. First you said that you tried nothing and next that you are trying to solve it already three years...

Comment: By ‘I tried nothing’ you should understand nothing conclusive. All my attempts hit the rocks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem is nearly identical to problem 5 of round 1 of the 2011-2012 USAMTS competition. They phrased it slightly differently, as their goal was to get two urns (which they called stacks of cards) to have an equal number, but from this configuration you can easily make one urn empty.

The solution is available in [this pdf](https://www.usamts.org/Solutions/Solutions_23_1.pdf).

Here is a more condensed version of the proof. The general strategy is to identify classes of scenarios in which victory is achievable and then work to broaden them until every possible scenario is covered.

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ represent the three numbers of balls in the urns, and without loss of generality assume that $x \le y \le z$.

**Case 0:** $x = 0$ or  $x = y$ or  $y = z$

Victory is trivial in this cases.

**Case 1:** $0 < x < y < z$ where $y = nx$ for some integer $n$

We can use the following process to win the game:

- While $x$ and $y$ are unequal

  - If $n$ is currently even, double $x$ by moving balls from urn $z$. This divides $n$ by 2.
  - If $n$ is currently odd, double $x$ by moving balls from urn $y$. This divides $n$ by 2, rounding down.

No matter the starting value of $n$, we eventually reach $n = 1$ which is Case 0.

**Case 2:** $0 < x < y < z$ where $y = nx + r$ for some integer $n$ and some remainder $0 < r < x$

The same algorithm as in Case 1 is used. Once that algorithm terminates, we are not left with two equal urns, but rather urn $y$ contains exactly $r$ more ball than urn $x$. This is because the presence of the extra $r$ balls present in urn $y$ at the start of the algorithm are completely untouched throughout the process.

Once we have the situation where $y_{new} = x_{new} + r$, we can double urn $x$ from $y$, leaving that urn to now have only $r$ balls remaining.  Since $r$ is less than the original value of $x$, we are left with a situation where one of our urns has fewer balls than any urns we began with.

Since the algorithm described in case 2 results in a strictly decreasing sequence of number of balls in the smallest urn, it is impossible to repeat this process indefinitely, and therefore must eventually end up in Case 1 or 0, so this algorithms always terminates.

Comment: $x=2$, $y=5\cdot2$. First step, you'll get $4$ and $8$. Then you get $8$ and $4$ and you are stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: For case 1, if $n$ is even, it should read "double $x$ by moving balls from urn $z$"

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Comment: The above pdf has given another solution to this problem as well. It is mentioned as "solution 2" . I would like to request you or someone else to explain this "Solution 2" in a simpler language. Thanks